# li:hover beginner's remark

Tags: css

I have divs inside li elements:

```
<ul id="tabs">   
    <li id="tab-1"> <div id="xxx"></div> </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

If in CSS I apply hover effect over li element

```
#tabs li:hover {....}
```

The effect is, as expected, applied on li and child div,

however if I make one space in between li and colon

```
#tabs li :hover {....}
```

effect applies only to child div

Is this normal? I'm a scripting beginner, and by reading different tutorials I got impression that white space does not make difference when script is executed. I tested this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: HTML and CSS are not scripting languages but markup languages. They do not execute anything but describe an architecture and styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#tabs li :hover {....}`  = `#tabs li *:hover {....}` (* = universal selector).

A space separates sub-selectors. This makes sense when you're concatenating multiple selectors:

Say, you want to select a `<div class="foo">`, but not `<a class="foo">` or `<div>`. The correct selector would be `div.foo` (element `<div>` with class `foo`).

If you add a space before the dot, you would be selecting a element with class `foo`, which is a child of `<div>`.

Back to your situation.

```
<div id="tabs">   #tabs                 #tabs
    <li>          li:hover              li
        <div>     div                   *:hover
                = #tabs li:hover div  = #tabs li *:hover
```

Comment: Note: a space selects **all** descendants. If you want to match direct childs, use `>`: `#tabs > li:hover > div`

Comment: Tnx for the fast reply. It has sense now.

Comment: @user1136011 *(comment on edited question)* Code blocks can be marked by prefixing text with four spaces; Backticks (`) are used to mark inline code. Also, if your question has been answered, mark the answer as "Accepted", so that others can see that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour. Space in CSS is separator. In this case you select `li` descendants.